# How do I align caption with table?

Tags: tables, captions, article

I have a table like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{
  labelsep=newline,
  justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  textfont=it,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{List of Important Predictors when Predicting Rearrest (Random Forests)}
\label{rearrest.rftop.20}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\hline
\textbf{Predictor} & \textbf{Importance}\\ 
\cline{1-2}
\hspace{2pt}1. Age at first arrest &    100 \\ 
\hspace{2pt}2. Number of tattoos &  98.59 \\ 
\hspace{2pt}3. Age &    98.57 \\ 
\hspace{2pt}4. Number of times convicted of misdemeanors &  95.78 \\ 
\hspace{2pt}5. Minor disciplinary incidents (annual rate) &     85.64 \\ 
\hspace{2pt}6. Number of times convicted of felonies &  85.51 \\ 
\hspace{2pt}7. Good time lost from disciplinary incidents (annual rate) &   79.67 \\ 
\hspace{2pt}8. Number of days served  (current incarceration) &     75.66 \\ 
\hspace{2pt}9. Number of times convicted of class B misdemeanors &  72.04 \\
10. Number of times convicted of State Jail Felonies &  69.47 \\ 
11. Number of times convicted of a  property offense &  65.36 \\ 
12. Number of times convicted of  class A misdemeanors &    58.95 \\ 
13. Number of times arrested for misdemeanors &     58.51 \\ 
14. Days sentenced (current incarceration) &    57.55 \\ 
15. Number of times convicted of drug possession &  50.31 \\ 
16. Number of times convicted of a drug offense &   50.16 \\ 
17. Number of times arrested for felonies &     49.94 \\ 
18. Years of education &    46.48 \\ 
19. Number of scars &   46.02 \\ 
20. Number of times arrested for a property offense &   44.43 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I align the caption with the table (i.e., move it to the right a little bit). Note: The Table number and caption need to remain on separate lines.

Comment: Why do you use `\hline` instead of `\toprule` and `\cline` instead of `\midrule`? And why do you insert that `\hspace`s? If you want the numbers to be aligned in any way, you should make them a standalone column.

Comment: The captions of tables, figures, etc, are supposed to be in specific place according to the documentclass and chosen styles... If you align this caption with this table the caption of next table will not be aligned with this caption and this will be a big mistake in typography... Anyway if you insist I suggest you to use a p column type for first column and a length that makes the table longer to start at the caption's horizontal start

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this?

[image]

you need to move `\caption` inside `threeparttable`.

off-topic:

- i suggest to use rules from `booktabs` for all horizontal lines in table
- for last column to use `S` column type from `siunitx` package
- for number on the beginning of table content  put in own column of `r` type
- predictor put in `\multicolumn{2}{l}{...}`
- and not on the end, for use of `threeparttable` you need to load in premable package `threeparttable`

*mwe*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{
  labelsep=newline,
  justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  textfont=it,
}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\label{rearrest.rftop.20}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{List of Important Predictors when Predicting Rearrest (Random Forests)}
\begin{tabular}{rlS[table-format=3.2]}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Predictor}} & \textbf{Importance}\\
    \midrule
 1.   & Age at first arrest &    100 \\
 2.   & Number of tattoos &  98.59 \\
 3.   & Age &    98.57 \\
 4.   & Number of times convicted of misdemeanors &  95.78 \\
 5.   & Minor disciplinary incidents (annual rate) &     85.64 \\
 6.   & Number of times convicted of felonies &  85.51 \\
 7.   & Good time lost from disciplinary incidents (annual rate) &   79.67 \\
 8.   & Number of days served  (current incarceration) &     75.66 \\
 9.   & Number of times convicted of class B misdemeanors &  72.04 \\
10.   & Number of times convicted of State Jail Felonies &  69.47 \\
11.   & Number of times convicted of a  property offense &  65.36 \\
12.   & Number of times convicted of  class A misdemeanors &    58.95 \\
13.   & Number of times arrested for misdemeanors &     58.51 \\
14.   & Days sentenced (current incarceration) &    57.55 \\
15.   & Number of times convicted of drug possession &  50.31 \\
16.   & Number of times convicted of a drug offense &   50.16 \\
17.   & Number of times arrested for felonies &     49.94 \\
18.   & Years of education &    46.48 \\
19.   & Number of scars &   46.02 \\
20.   & Number of times arrested for a property offense &   44.43 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some improvements: a right-aligned automatic numbering of the rows. Incidentally, the trick was to nest `\caption` *inside* the `threeparttable` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, caption, threeparttable}

\captionsetup[table]{
  labelsep=newline,
  justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  textfont=it,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\label{rearrest.rftop.20}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{List of Important Predictors when Predicting Rearrest (Random Forests)}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\arabic{tabenum}.}
\begin{tabular}{ >{\tabitem\hspace*{\labelsep}}r@{}lc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Predictor}} & \textbf{Importance}\\
\midrule
& Age at first arrest & 100 \\
& Number of tattoos & 98.59 \\
& Age & 98.57 \\
& Number of times convicted of misdemeanors & 95.78 \\
& Minor disciplinary incidents (annual rate) & 85.64 \\
& Number of times convicted of felonies & 85.51 \\
& Good time lost from disciplinary incidents (annual rate) & 79.67 \\
& Number of days served (current incarceration) & 75.66 \\
& Number of times convicted of class B misdemeanors & 72.04 \\
& Number of times convicted of State Jail Felonies & 69.47 \\
& Number of times convicted of a property offense & 65.36 \\
& Number of times convicted of class A misdemeanors & 58.95 \\
& Number of times arrested for misdemeanors & 58.51 \\
& Days sentenced (current incarceration) & 57.55 \\
& Number of times convicted of drug possession & 50.31 \\
& Number of times convicted of a drug offense & 50.16 \\
& Number of times arrested for felonies & 49.94 \\
& Years of education & 46.48 \\
& Number of scars & 46.02 \\
& Number of times arrested for a property offense & 44.43 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]